# matplotlib presentation with regards to plt.show() vs semi-colon

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

Not so much a problem but rather what is the 'industry standard' with regards to
`plt.plot();` and `plt.show()` following `plt.plot()`?

In my experience so far, it seems `plt.plot()` then `plt.show()` seems more common, but I'm looking to draw on more experienced programmers.

Comment: Note that this "trick" to use a semicolon or `plt.show()` at the end of a cell is only relevant in a Jupyter notebook. By default, Jupyter shows the *return value*  of the last line of the cell, which is *nothing* in the case of `plt.show()` (returns `None`) or the empty statement created by the semicolon.  As the semicolon is quite an anti-pattern in Python, personally I'd suggest using `plt.show()`.  `plt.show()` is often necessary when running stand-alone Python code.  Interactive environments usually show the plot also when `plt.show()` isn't called explicitly.

Comment: I was thinking similarly which is a nice feeling. I'll continue to `plt.show( )` then, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semi-colon in Python denotes separation, rather than termination. It allows you to write multiple statements on the same line. For example instead of writing:

```py
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

You can use a semi colon to write these 3 lines of code on a single line:

`plt.plot(x, y); plt.show()`

In my opinion, I think that the code is more readable/understandable when writing the code on seperate lines, however some people may think different. It is not always good to write on seperate lines because when using list comprehensions, you can write in 10 lines or 1 line, which means they take up less space and computer memory.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, I appreciate it. I shall continue to `plt.show()` then but will likely keep them on different lines.